# Checking web3 version metamask is using

Tags: web3js

I have installed metamask. When I open any page in the browser, go into the console and type `web3` I can see that the object is present:

```
> web3
Proxy { <target>: {…}, <handler>: {…} }
```

How do I check the version of web3 injected into the page? The command `web3.version` fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to this [Summary of Breaking Changes](https://docs.metamask.io/guide/provider-migration.html#replacing-window-web3). I think web3 have been replaced, so u can use `ethereum` instead for your purpose.